# How to make a plot show everytime after a run through a for loop and not let the lines stack up

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, autocorrelation

I am trying to show 4 autocorrelation plots, 1 for each column with values of my dataframe. I'm using a for loop to make it show 4 times. But the result is that the autocorrelation plot only shows one time with 4 lines instead of showing up 4 times with each plot only 1 line.
My code is as followed:
(Ignore the libraries that are being imported but not used)

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize': (5, 3), 'figure.dpi': 120}
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from dateutil.parser import parse
from scipy import signal
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot

# Import Data
ser = pd.read_csv('Time series analysis dataset Weekly.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date')
ser = ser[ser.YearOfDate != 2020]

ValueNames = ['Europe', 'Total', 'International', 'Distributor']
ColorsList = ['Blue','Green','Orange','Purple','Brown']

# Draw Plot
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize':(7,4), 'figure.dpi':120})
for ValueRound in range(0,len(ValueNames)):
   autocorrelation_plot(ser[f'{ValueNames[ValueRound]}'].tolist())
```

The result I get by running the script is

[image]

Because of the for loop, 4 lines have been plotted, 1 for each value name. The desired result is to have 4 seperate plots with each 1 line. In other scripts where I use a normal plot I used plt.plot.show() within the for loop. This results in 4 plots with only 1 line. How van I do this for an autocorrelation plot?

Im following this guide for my time series analysis https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/time-series-analysis-python/, i've based my script on the script in chapter 14: How to test for seasonality.

Here is another picture with the desired plot. To get this plot I've only looped threw the for loop 1 time, resulting in only ONE line for the value name Europe. See

[image]

Comment: What the **** lol. I thought i tried that and it said that it didn't work because its an autocorrelation plot. I've now added the plt.show() and it does work. Thankyou, you've resolved my prblem @ombk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem by adding `plt.show()` at the end of the for loop instead of `plt.plot.show()`